# How do I show/submit items on the payflowlink.paypal.com page and what are my alternatives?

Tags: paypal, payflowlink

Is there a way to show the list of products on a payflowlink.paypal.com page similar to what you can do when you post data to PayPal Payments Standard(https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr).

From the documentation it doesn't look like it is possible to use fields like **item_name** like I do on PayPal Payments Standard, so I am looking for an simple alternative.

I could use the PayPal Payments Standard but the page will display the email address not the logo configured in manager.paypal.com.

Thank you

Comment: You can use the hdrimg parameter in your Payments Standard code to include a URL to your logo.  That way it'll use that instead of your email address.

Comment: Hmm, I am still not sure if I can use Standard Payments with accounts that are managed in manager.paypal.com(I think it's business account). From the list of services I can see: Hosted Checkout Pages, Payflow SDK/API (Limited Access) and Paypal Express Checkout but no Standard Payments.

Comment: When you have an account like that you can actually log in to both manager.paypal.com and the regular paypal.com (as long as PayPal is your merchant processor.)  You also get full access to all API's on both sides, so you would simply log into PayPal.com and generate your button like usual, or you can use the cart upload method.